# Lebesgue Outer Measure of $\mathbb Q$ from the Definition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Define $\lambda^*:\wp\left(\mathbb R\right)\to\left[0,\infty\right]$ by

$$\lambda^*\left(E\right)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(b_n-a_n\right):E\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(a_n,b_n\right)\right\}.\tag{$\star$}$$

In other words, $\lambda^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Clearly, $\lambda^*\left(\left\{q\right\}\right)=0$ for every $q\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, since outer measures are countably subadditive, $\lambda^*\left(\mathbb Q\right)=0$;

$$\lambda^*\left(\mathbb Q\right)=\lambda^*\left(\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}\left\{q\right\}\right)\leq\sum_{q\in\mathbb Q}\lambda^*\left(\left\{q\right\}\right)=0.$$

However, how does this follow from $\left(\star\right)$ alone? I am having a hard time coming up with a sequence of collections of intervals whose unions contain $\mathbb Q$ and whose sums approach zero since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, that's what I was looking for. Thank you. I promise that I did try searching first, lol.

Comment: Usually when you write your question, suggestions come up on both the right hand side as well as when you are typing your title, of duplicate or related questions. Also, the first question linked on the right is the duplicate. Next time, you can ensure using these that you do not end up posting duplicates. Also, since this question is now answered, I request you to close it.